# Assistance listing pictures with text underneath

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css. I've gotten a college assignment to create a webpage and i went somewhat overboard on the design something that was supposed to be simple has gotten somewhat complicated.

I'm currently trying to list the cast of a tv show down the left hand side of my page.

->[Wire-frame example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH9NL.png) <-

Everything I have tried has failed, I'm feeling beaten here is an example of what I've managed to do trying methods i know or have found online hoping it would do the trick.

->[Current Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpH5m.png)<-

->[Link to current HTML](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/767d3d838b7de58503d9f076645cac74)<-

As you can see in the wire-frame, I'm ideally wanting their names centred under the pictures, which is my struggle.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Your current code would help a lot more than a screenshot of the result.

Comment: Apologies, just trying to figure out the best way to upload the code without making the post massive. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Thanks! I'll write an answer now.

Comment: There we go, uploaded the current code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the label and the image belonging to one actor are not grouped. Put them inside a `<div>` container.

```
<div>
  <div class="actor">
    <img src="Pictures/willingham.jpg" class="actor-image">
    <div class="actor-label">Travis</div>
  </div>
  <div class="actor">
    <img src="Pictures/willingham.jpg" class="actor-image">
    <div class="actor-label">Laura</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the new CSS:

```
.actor {
  display: inline-block;
}

.actor-image {
  width: 86px;
}

.actor-label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Note that I also improved a lot of other things like removing unnecessary code or using CSS to style elements instead of HTML (cause that's what CSS is for). If you want the labels to look different just change/add the properties inside the `.actor-label` selector.

Comment: This is 100% what i was looking for, You completely hit the nail on the head. Perfect, Been trying to fix my problem for 4 hours now with no luck and you fixed it in 5 mins flat!